# How to remove auto generate Enum field schema in drf-spectacular

Tags: python, django, drf-spectacular

How to remove auto generate Enum field schema in `drf-spectacular`

here my `SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS`:

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'TITLE': 'Python Base Code',
    'VERSION': '1.0.0',
    'SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA': False,
    'SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX_TRIM': True,
    'SERVERS': [{'url': env('SWAGGER_SERVER')},],
    'PREPROCESSING_HOOKS': ["custom.url_remover.preprocessing_filter_spec"],  
    'COMPONENT_SPLIT_PATCH': False,
    }
```

Comment: Paste your tried code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to hide/remove schemas of enums (which are auto-generated) in Swagger-UI, then try this `SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS` instand of yours.

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
   'TITLE': 'Python Base Code',
   'VERSION': '1.0.0',
   'SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA': False,
   'SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX_TRIM': True,
   'SERVERS': [{'url': env('SWAGGER_SERVER')},],
   'PREPROCESSING_HOOKS': ["custom.url_remover.preprocessing_filter_spec"],  
   'COMPONENT_SPLIT_PATCH': False,
   'POSTPROCESSING_HOOKS': []
}
```

i just overwrite the default `POSTPROCESSING_HOOKS` from this

> 'POSTPROCESSING_HOOKS': [
> 'drf_spectacular.hooks.postprocess_schema_enums'
> ]

to this

> 'POSTPROCESSING_HOOKS': []

This should work